# How to calculate how many days from today's date based on a column that contains dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe, one column contains multiple dates called 'date', I want to convert it to the days calculated from today's date (2020-07-04), here's the code:

```
profile['membership_date'] = pd.to_datetime(profile['became_member_on'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
```

the column is like this :

```
0       2017-02-12
1       2017-07-15
2       2018-07-12
3       2017-05-09
4       2017-08-04
5       2018-04-26
```

Then we get today's date:

```
today_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#calculate days, I tried two different ways but still getting error

profile['membership_date'] - today_date

profile['membership_days'] = (profile['membership_date'] - today_date).days

#error:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'str'
```

Can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: try removing this part `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, you don't want to cast it to string if you're doing datetime comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) to subtract the `membership_date` column from the [`pd.Timestamp.now`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.now.html) which returns a series with `timedelta` objects, finally use [`Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) to get the integer representation of number of days elapsed between two dates.

```
profile['membership_days'] = (
    profile['membership_date'].sub(pd.Timestamp.now()).dt.days
)
```

Result:

```
# print(profile)
        Date  membership_days
0 2017-02-12            -1239
1 2017-07-15            -1086
2 2018-07-12             -724
3 2017-05-09            -1153
4 2017-08-04            -1066
5 2018-04-26             -801
```